# lsof and listening ports

Tags: osx, lsof

I am trying to get all the processes listening for a network connection on Mac OS X. `netstat` does not have the `-p` option and I am trying with lsof

```
lsof -i -sTCP:LISTEN
```

gives me a fair list of listening processes but not all. I can for example telnet to port 10080 where I have a process listening for a connection but this is not shown in the output of `lsof`. What am I missing?

```
$ telnet localhost 10080
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

but

```
$ sudo lsof -n -i | grep 10080
$
```

Comment: Does the output of lsof say `amanda` instead of 10080?

Comment: @JonLin I didn't notice that the `-n` only affects addresses and not ports. To get port **numbers** I have to use `-P` too. Thanks

Comment: @JonLin: but you have post `lsof -i -sTCP:LISTEN` , and it without the `-n` and it didn't reveal the 10080 too. So you have to use the `-P`.

Answer (score 121):

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n
```

All return the same 32 entries (`... | wc -l`) on my heavily used Lion MBP.

`-P -n` prevents `lsof` from doing name resolution, and it doesn't block.  Missing either one of these, it can be very slow.

For UDP: `sudo lsof -iUDP -P -n | egrep -v '(127|::1)'`.  Without `-n` and `-P`, it takes a long time.

Reminder: This does not include firewall settings.

Comment: Yes the problem was the missing `-P`. I wrongly assumed `-n` applied not only to IPs but port numbers too.

Comment: using `sudo lsof -iTCP:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN` will check if port 3000 is listening

Answer (score 9):

> sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN

This command shows all network files, listening with TCP protocol on all the open ports.

> sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:`5432` -sTCP:LISTEN

This command just shows the one listening on port `5432`

---

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this shell function you can stick in your `~/.bashrc` that gives you a nice report:

```bsh
ports() {
    (
        echo 'PROC PID USER x IPV x x PROTO BIND PORT'
        (
            sudo lsof +c 15 -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n | tail -n +2
            sudo lsof +c 15 -iUDP -P -n | tail -n +2 | egrep -v ' (127\.0\.0\.1|\[::1\]):'
        ) | sed -E 's/ ([^ ]+):/ \1 /' | sort -k8,8 -k5,5 -k1,1 -k10,10n
    ) | awk '{ printf "%-16s %-6s %-9s %-5s %-7s %s:%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$9,$10 }'
}
```